# Getting specific indexed distinct values in nested lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a nested list of around 1 million records like:

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c', ...], ['d', 'b', 'e', ...], ['f', 'z', 'g', ...],...]
```

I want to get the distinct values of inner lists on second index, so that my resultant list be like:

```
resultant = ['b', 'z', ...]
```

I have tried nested loops but its not fast, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the unique items you can use `collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys()` in order to keep the order and unique items (because of using hashtable fro keys) and use `zip()` to get the second items.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(zip(my_lists)[2]))
```

In python 3.x since `zip()` returns an iterator you can do this:

```
colls = zip(my_lists)
next(colls)
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(next(colls)))
```

Or use a generator expression within `dict.formkeys()`:

```
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(i[1] for i in my_lists))
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'b', 'e'], ['f', 'z', 'g']]
>>> 
>>> list(OrderedDict().fromkeys(sub[1] for sub in lst))
['b', 'z']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unzip the list of lists then choice the second tuple with set like below :
This code take 4.05311584473e-06 millseconds, in my laptop

```
list(set(zip(*lst)[1]))
```

Input :

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'b', 'e'], ['f', 'z', 'g']]
```

Out put :

```
['b', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that work for you?

```
result = set([inner_list[1] for inner_list in l])
```

Comment: Added casting to set to my answer.

Comment: @lokesh1729 OP did not specify that he/she wants to preserve the order.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options.

Set comprehension:

```
res = {x[1] for x in l}
```

I think numpy arrays work faster than list/set comprehensions, so converting this list to an array and then using array functions can be faster. Here:

```
import numpy as np

res = np.unique(np.array(l)[:, 1])
```

Let me explain: `np.array(l)` converts the list to a 2d array, then `[:, 1]` take the second column (starting to count from 0) which consists of the second item of each sublist in the original `l`, and finally taking only unique values using `np.unique`.